# CAN Rx Line between STM32 and MCP2561

Tags: stm32, can, logic-level

I discover a problem on my design, with a STM32F042K6 MCU and a MCP2561 Can Transceiver.
I can send some frames on the CAN Bus but i can't receive any frames.
When i put my scope probe on the CAN Rx Line between the MCU and the Transceiver o observe a bad low level voltage like this :

[image]

I have checked, this MCU Input is 5V tolerant.

What is the reason of this bad low level voltage ?
I think it's why my MCU don't receive any acknowledge and any frames.

Is there a problem on the Transceiver or on the MCU ?

Thank's for your help !

---

It seems there is a problem on the ACK bit transmission : 
I don't understand why. Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a ground shift. Check if there are no parasitic resistances between Micro and Transceiver Grounds. Is it supplied from the same power source?

Comment: It's power from two different regulators because the MCP2561 needs 5V and the MCU needs 3.3V. I checked the Tx Line and the levels are good (0V - 3.3V). It seems there is no resistances between MCU Ground and MCP2561 Ground.

Comment: MCU ground and MCP2564 ground should be the same. As in, short circuit. Open circuit means this won't work properly.

Comment: Yes, It's the same Ground !!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Thank's guys, i'm so sorry it was due to a bad solder on my MCP2561 Gnd Pin.
On the TX Side, i'm facing a problem due to the ACK, i always encountered a timeout issue when i want to send a Can Frame :
[image]

And the frame is received multiples times on the other CAN Equipment : 
When i send one frame, the MCU seems to send multiples frames until it reach the timeout.